# jsdom error: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, web-scraping, jsdom

I'm getting the segfault trying to render this page (for example)

https://www.google.com/search?q=sinus+infection+symptoms

```
jsdom.env
  url: "https://www.google.com/search?q=sinus+infection+symptoms"
  scripts: ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"]
  features:
    FetchExternalResources:   ["script"]
    ProcessExternalResources: ["script"]
    SkipExternalResources:    false

  done: (err, window) ->
    console.log err    # -> no error
    $("#res .g-blk")   # -> works
```

I want to set a timeout so the rest of the elements render

```
done: (err, window) ->
  setTimeout (->
    console.log err    # -> no error
    $("#res .g-blk")   # -> works
  ), 1000
```

The error is only thrown if the window hangs around for too long. This will segfault:

```
done: (err, window) ->
  setTimeout (->
    console.log err
    $("#res .g-blk")
  ), 5000
```

Is this because an error occurs rendering the page? How can I catch the error and continue parsing?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in Contextify and should actually be fixed by [this](https://github.com/brianmcd/contextify/pull/138) patch. Are you maybe using a Contextify version < 0.1.10?

Comment: The contextify version is 0.1.12. I just did `npm install jsdom` and let it do its thing.